# Custom maps in Google Maps / Google Map Maker

Tags: google-maps

I want to make a custom Google Map to show someone points of interest in an area. Ideally, I’d like to drop pins on the points of interest and then add notes and images (which I’ve taken) to these pins.

Is this possible with Google Maps / Google Map Maker? I’m aware you can make a map, but these seem to be for public consumption. Ideally, I’d like it to be private—unlisted / view only with the link. Also, I couldn’t see a way to annotate / add images to these maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new [Google Maps Engine](https://mapsengine.google.com/map/) you can do everything you want.

There is a tutorial that takes you through the basics of setting up your own map, but it does miss mentioning that in the information field of a pin you can add `<img>` tags.

You will still have to host those images somewhere else.

All maps are private by default, you have to share them in the same way as you do on Google Drive.

Comment: Thanks, ive tried linking an image (which is hosted with imgur) but i cant get it to save when i click add they just disappear any ideas ? - Ive made a video of whats happening [HERE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVh6mPyiwmo&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Sam, I'm not sure what's happening. Works for me using Chrome on Mint GNU/Linux (hat tip to FSF). I do know that the maps engine light is still in beta (actual beta, not Gmail 5 years beta) and the image functionality seems [pretty new](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/maps-engine/image|sort:date/maps-engine/tL56CmUjUI4/yE99xUKR3boJ). Might be worth submitting a report? Or waiting a couple of days?

Comment: Cool ill give it a try in chorme

Comment: @sam, Video missing.

Comment: @TomHorwood, any updates?

Comment: @Pacerier - I'm pretty sure you can now just click the image button at the bottom of the tooltip editing form, so this question should now be redundant